# Accessing Data from Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The below is a pandas basic assignment question.

> Create a series named heights_A with values 176.2, 158.4, 167.6,
> 156.2, and 161.4. These values represent heights of 5 students of class A.
>
> Label each student as s1, s2, s3, s4, and s5.
>
> Create another series named weights_A with values 85.1, 90.2, 76.8,
> 80.4, and 78.9. These values represent weights of 5 students of class A.
>
> Label each student as s1, s2, s3, s4, and s5.
>
> Create a dataframe named df_A, which holds the height and weight of
> five students s1, s2, s3, s4 and s5.
>
> Label the columns as Student_height and Student_weight, respectively.
>
> Select the column df_A referring to student heights, and store it in
> the variable height. Note: Specify the required column name inside
> square brackets.
>
> Print the type of object of the variable height.

Tried with the below code till now, but the checker seems to think height data type is not correct.
Not sure where is this being incorrect.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



heights_A =  pd.Series([176.2, 158.4, 167.6, 156.2, 161.4])

heights_A.index = ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4','s5']


weights_A = pd.Series([85.1, 90.2, 76.8, 80.4 , 78.9])

weights_A.index = ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4','s5']



df_A = pd.DataFrame()

df_A['Student_height'] = heights_A

df_A['Student_weight'] = weights_A

height = df_A[['Student_height']]
height.dtypes
```

Not sure what is incorrect with this height datatype part

Comment: Could you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try:

```
height = df_A['Student_height']
#height.dtypes #dont use this as they are asking for the type of object 
print(type(height))
```

type() function will give you the type of the height object. If you try with object.dtype it will give the datatype.
When you were using double square brackets the heights variable is a df, when you just use single square brackets a series is returned. Seems like your question wants a series returned.

Comment: Seems the issue is only with the height = df_A[['Student_height']]
height.dtypes part w.r.t assigning and the datatype . is there anything missing from this